# TableToExport download excel without header

Tags: jqgrid, export-to-excel

I want to export jqgrid in excel with .xlsx format.

I am able to export using below code

```
let table = document.getElementById("grid"); 
    TableToExcel.convert(table, {
     name: 'export.xlsx', // fileName you could use any name
      sheet: {
           name: 'Sheet 1' // sheetName
            }
       });
```

I have given TableToExcel reference:

"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"

But in excel, it does not display header of the table. it exported without header.

Can anyone help me in that? how I can add header in excel?

Comment: jqGrid has two tables one for the header and other for the data, so in this case you will need to manually build the file using the generic module from which the tableToexcel is build. For this purpose use [excel/excels lib](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#tables)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //View 
 <a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Home" , new {  ID = @Session["ID"] })" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Export to Excel</a> 

//Controller
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int ID)
                {
                                            
                        var grid = new GridView();
                        grid.DataSource = from p in results
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              column1 = p.xyz,
                                              colum 2 = p.abc
                                          };
                        grid.DataBind();
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + job_number + ".xls");
                        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                        grid.RenderControl(htw);
                        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                        Response.End();
                        return View("view_name");
                    }
```